# calculate time difference in milliseconds excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, milliseconds

How do i calculate time difference **in milliseconds** between two columns where value of time has milliseconds component ... i.e. 16:33:44:056. Please refer to column E and J in pic .. i want to calculate **difference in milli seconds between J and E** ... [image]

I have tried using the following formula to alculate difference in milli seconds but its giving incorrect results. =((RIGHT(J1,3))-(RIGHT(E1,3)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears your date/time is a text value.

A "real" time value would normally be seen as `16:11:52.052`

But by replacing the last `:` with a `.`, excel will see it as a real time and ordinary math can be done.

Excel stores date/time as days and fractions of a day.

So a formula that should work:

```
=ROUND((SUBSTITUTE(J1,":",".",3)-SUBSTITUTE(E1,":",".",3))*86400000,0)
```

Format the result as General or as Number with no decimal places

Answer (score 4):

If you change the format of your time columns, and the column to show the difference, to

```
hh:mm:ss.000
```

You can simply use subtraction:

[image]

<sub>(You'll have to tweak the actual cells to have `.` before the milliseconds, just formatting won't do it)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
=(J1-E1)*1000*60*60*24
```

or more concisely

```
=(J1-E1)*86400000
```

Then format your formula column to general.

This assumes the data is actually stored as datetime and not a text value.

Comment: yes, but in my case will also have to replace ':' after seconds to '.', u may edit your answer if you want to :)

Answer (score 1):

If the part of that string corresponding to hours, minutes and seconds is always the same, and time in J is always bigger than time in E, you could do:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(J1;3))-VALUE(RIGHT(E1;3))
```